# RAND_MAX exhibiting unusual behavior upon recasting

Tags: c

I wish to generate random numbers between 0 and 1. (Obviously, this has application elsewhere.)

My test code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main() {
double uR;
srand(1);
for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
    uR = rand()/(RAND_MAX+1.000);
    printf("%d \n", uR);
    }
}
```

And here's the output after the code is compiled with GCC:

```
gcc -ansi -std=c99 -o rand randtest.c
./rand
0 
-251658240 
910163968 
352321536 
-528482304
```

Upon inspection, it turns out that casting the integer RAND_MAX to a double has the effect of changing its value from 2147483647 to -4194304. This occurs regardless of the method used to change RAND_MAX to type double; so far, I've tried `(double)RAND_MAX` and `double max = RAND_MAX` as well.

Why does the number's value change? How can I stop that from happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't print a `double` with `%d`. If you use `%f`, it works just fine.

Comment: It is frankly embarrassing how many mistakes I've made TODAY that involve the printf() statement. Thank you very much.

Comment: @Ragaxus: if you can't find an option for your compiler that warns you about such mistakes, it is time to get yourself a better compiler.  Using GCC and `-Wall`, the problem would have been diagnosed by the compiler (as a warning).

Comment: Even better, compile everything with `-Werror`, that will turn warnings into errors. Only turn it off if you really hit a wall.

Answer (score 1):

You are passing a double (`uR`) to `printf` when it expects a `signed int`. You should cast it or print with `%f`

```
printf("%d \n", (int)uR);
```

Comment: Casting a value between `0` and `1` to `int` has very little value (pardon pun).

Comment: Yes, that is why I told him to printf with `%f` too. I also tried to demonstrate how to cast a value.

Answer (score 1):

You are printing a double value as a decimal integer - which is causing you confusion.

Use `%.6f` or something similar.